# ARM Template not generating resource ID using function

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm-template

I have following ARM template where I'm trying to get resources IDs of two API connections created outside this template in same resource group where this template is being deployed:

```
"parameters": {
"$connections": {
    "value": {
        "office365": {
            "connectionId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections','office365_connection')]",
            "connectionName": "office365_connection",
            "id": "[concat('/subscriptions/',subscription().id,'/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/',resourceGroup().location,'/managedApis/office365')]"
        },
        "azuremonitorlogs": {
            "connectionId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections','monitor_logs_connection')]",
            "connectionName": "monitor_logs_connection",
            "id": "[concat('/subscriptions/',subscription().id,'/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/',resourceGroup().location,'/managedApis/azuremonitorlogs')]"
        }
    }
}
```

}

It is complaining that `id` is not defined when I'm referencing the items like `"@parameters('$connections')['azuremonitorlogs']['connectionId']"`.

I'm deploying the template via Terraform resource template deployment if that is the culprit.

Comment: Two issues that I faced: 1. `/subscriptions/` was superfluous as `subscription().id` has it. Second, in `connectionId`, `resourceGroup().name` is required instead of `resourceGroup().location`.

Answer (score 0):

I deployed service bus managed api connection using terraform:

```
resource "azurerm_api_connection" "example" {
  name                = "kaexample-connection"
 resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  managed_api_id      = data.azurerm_managed_api.example.id
  display_name        = "Example 1"

  parameter_values = {
    connectionString = azurerm_servicebus_namespace.example.default_primary_connection_string
  }

  tags = {
    Hello = "World"
  }

  lifecycle {      
    ignore_changes = [parameter_values]
  }
}
```

Check below code for getting resource id of the api connection:

I deployed the servie bus .

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment" "example" {
  name                = "new-template-deployment"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  deployment_mode     = "Incremental"
  template_content    = <<TEMPLATE
  {
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {},
  "resources": [],
  "outputs": {
    "api_connection_resource_id": {
      "type": "string",      
     "value": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/resourceGroups/', '${data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name}', '/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/','managedApis/servicebus')]"
   
    }
  }
}
TEMPLATE
}
```

[image]

[image]

**In your case check as below:**

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "defaultValue": {},
            "type": "object"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [],
    "outputs": {
        "api_connection_resource_id": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[reference(parameters('$connections')['office365']).id]"
        }
    }
}
```

The id property is not a valid property for a connection object in an ARM template. Instead, you can use the resourceId function to construct the ID of the connection object.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "office365": {
                    "connectionId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections','office365_connection')]",
                    "connectionName": "office365_connection"
                },
                "azuremonitorlogs": {
                    "connectionId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections','monitor_logs_connection')]",
                    "connectionName": "monitor_logs_connection"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "office365_connection_id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections','office365_connection')]",
        "monitor_logs_connection_id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections','monitor_logs_connection')]"
    },
    "resources": [],
    "outputs": {
        "office365_connection_resource_id": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[concat(resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/', variables('office365_connection_id'))]"
        },
        "monitor_logs_connection_resource_id": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[concat(resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/', variables('monitor_logs_connection_id'))]"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to concat strings, `resourceId()` function gives the correct value as I mentioned in my comment. I was passing wrong parameters.